# Could not be able to keep image permanently in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have been tried to load a image from gallery an keep it permanently in app. But when I move to a different route and return to the image route previously loaded image has been disappeared.
'''

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('test'),
  ),
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Upload a picture'),
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            final image =
                await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
            if (image == null) return;
            final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
            log('imagevalue $image');
            final name = basename(image.path);
            final imagefile = File('${directory.path}/$name');
            final imagePermanent =
                await File(image.path).copy(imagefile.path);
            setState(() {
              _image = imagePermanent;
              log('_imageV $_image');
            });
          } on PlatformException catch (e) {
            log(e.toString());
          }
        },
      ),
      _image != null
          ? Image.file(
              _image!,
              height: 160,
              width: 160,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            )
          : const Icon(Icons.flutter_dash),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

'''

Answer (score 0):

to keep images or any kind of data in your app u should use a database like firbase or mySql to store images then retrieve in in ur app